# TypeError: Failed to fetch and POST fetch status = canceled

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I am passing user input data from React js to node js i.e backend, by using **POST fetch api** and successfully storing the data to my database. But **fetch api** is not returning the object successfully and showing me network status equal to **canceled** in google devtool.
I tried every thing but I don't know how to solve it. Thanks.

**Error Screenshot**
[image: Headers screenshot devtool]

**CustomerRegistration.jsx**

```
const onSubmit = async (e) => {

        const { fname, lname, email, password, address } = state;

        await fetch('/customer-registration', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email, password: password, address: address
            })
        }).then((res)=>{
            console.log(`this is my res ${res}`);
            window.alert('Customer Registration successfull');
        }).catch((error)=>{
            window.alert(error);
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

**Routers.js**

```
router.post('/customer-registration',async(req,res)=>{
    
    const {fname,lname,email,password,address}=req.body;
    
    try {
        const valid=await myModel.findOne({email:email});
        if(valid){
            const flag=true;
           console.log('Email already exist');
        }else{

            const finalData=new myModel({fname,lname,email,password,address});
            const data=await finalData.save();
            if(data){
                console.log('Data saved to db');
                console.log(data);
                res.json(data);
            } 
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Data not saved');
    }

})
```

Comment: You do not cancel the form submission.... You can clearly see the form submission happens in the line after the cancelled request in the network calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are not ensuring your nodejs returns a response.

```
router.post('/customer-registration',async(req,res)=>{
    
    const {fname,lname,email,password,address}=req.body;
    
    try {
        const valid=await myModel.findOne({email:email});
        if(valid){
            const flag=true;
           console.log('Email already exist');
           
        }else{

            const finalData=new myModel({fname,lname,email,password,address});
            const data=await finalData.save();
            if(data){
                console.log('Data saved to db');
                console.log(data);
                return res.json(data);
            } 

           return res.json({ok: false }) //you need to ensure you return something.
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Data not saved');
        return res.status(400).end() // you need to return something even if it's an error.
    }

})
```

Comment: are you calling onSubmit from button, or is it from `<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>`? If you are using <form> can you please include `e.preventDefault` in your onSubmit function?

Comment: Thanks brother that's work perfectly. 1 question raised at this point as you can see in Routers.js code a variable name flag, i want to access its value in CustomerRegistration.jsx how can i do that. Thanks.

Comment: you can return it as a response..... `res.json({ flag: true })`